# Use the same package name with the new app version?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app in the play store . I'm coding a new version of the app using a brand new project (i want to re-code everything) that uses the same package name. if i publish this new version of the app  will the users get it as an update? I know this is a noob question but i want to be sure . thnx

Comment: you will not probably be able to upload a complete new app with the same package name in a different "slot" so you will probably need to update your current app.

Comment: As long as the package name is the same and you sign it with the same key, then you can update the current application in the Play Store.

Comment: thnx for the replies

Comment: @zozelfelfo, you either mean something different, or you're incorrect.